# the ExpandableListView ignore SetSelectedChild() method

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I use the code

```
ExpandableListView expandListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
expandListView.setAdapter(adapter);
Boolean flag = expandListView.setSelectedChild(1, 1, true);
```

but it didn't work. Nothing happened. The group didn't expand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer here:
[ExpandableListView ignores setSelectedChild()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775838/expandablelistview-ignores-setselectedchild)

calling ExpandableListView.expandGroup(int); did the job